# ActiveRecord Connection Adapter return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activerecord

I had a bit more complex sql-query which i decided to use plain `sql` rather than writing it with AR. I wrapped the sql-statement inside ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query` .

The method basically looks like that:

```
def sc_agent
  return ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SQL").as_json
end
```

The serializer `as_json` gives me a json hash with json strings. So also id's are now strings

```
{"id":"123","age":"99"}
```

On standard queries where i  use AR i receive nicely 
 formatted json with the correct types.

How can i retain the correct types of all the values when using the ConnectionAdapter directly? Thanks for everything!

Comment: have you tried `find_by_sql` method? like that: `Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ? AND created > ?", author_id, start_date]`. More info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html

Comment: Great i did not know this one. Working! Thanks!

Comment: @AndreyS you should put that in an answer so that others find it easily and it can be accepted

Comment: @jaydel, sure, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_by_sql` method.

Example: `Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ? AND created > ?", author_id, start_date]`.

More info is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html